# How to override the default plan branch configuration?

Tags: bamboo

Currently we are in the process of migrating our projects from jenkins to bamboo. In this process, I am looking for an option in bamboo plan for a plan branch to be created when a new branch is created in the bitbucket repo and also when pull request is created.

As I see in the branch configuration of a plan, it is possible only to choose one option (new branch or pull request) for plan branch. is there any way where i can choose both options? Can I override the configuration using shell script? our bamboo server is currently running version 6.10.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo doesn't support multiple options for plan branch creation. What's the reason to have both options?
Before you create PR VCS branch already exists so why option to create plan branch on Bitbucket branch creation is not enough?

Comment: Thanks for your response. our main concern is that pull requests are validated before merging the code into the target branch. As bamboo has an option to merge in to target and build the merge. If this build is successful then pull request can be approved. Can i do it using some script task?